# how to get range value on change in textbox in asp.net mvc using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have range tag inside partial view and that partial view contains range tag and textbox so on change of range i want to show the changed value in textbox i am achieving this with single range tag but i am using asp.net MVC and want to write jquery to get it done dynamically on change of with Id = 1 only that value should be show in that particular textbox and so on.

```
Here is my html code

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
        <input type="range" class="range custom-range" min="5" max="180" data-cid="@Model.CatId"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <input type="text" class="rangeValue form-control" data-cid="@Model.CatId" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[data-cid=' + $('.range').data('cid') + ']').change(function () {
        $('input[data-cid=' + $('.rangeValue').data('cid') + ']').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

i have written this jquery but it still works for only one partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class selector` to archive your requirement instead of `data-cid` as below

```
$('input.custom-range').change(function () {
        $('input.rangeValue').val($(this).val());
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.custom-range').change(function () {
        $('input.rangeValue').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
        <input type="range" class="range custom-range" min="5" max="180" data-cid="100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <input type="text" class="rangeValue form-control" data-cid="123" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want it dyanamic i want to used based on data-cid

Comment: @shreyas35 just use the selector with `data-cid` like: `$('input.custom-range[data-cid=100]')`